# Using a commercial product that uses open source licenses

Tags: licensing, telerik

I am using Telerik Rad Controls for Silverlight that is intended to be used in a commercial product which seems perfectly fine as long as I say in the about box that it uses it I believe.

However, Telerik has a folder containing 12 licenses that it uses. Now my question is, do I need to redistribute all of these licenses along with my product also? I am thinking that if you use a number of products each with different licenses that you soon end up having a large number in the finished product. Is that correct?

Comment: The actual contents of those 12 licenses will describe what you can and can't do.  There's no general rule.

Comment: @DrewDormann Assuming that all of the licenses Telerik use allow commercial redistribution (which is a pretty reasonable assumption here) it might be that even though their license doesn't state it explicitly it might be that you still need to have copies of the licenses even if you don't directly use them then?

Comment: Best to ask Telerik directly.  I'm a stranger on the internet...I sometimes give good programming advice, but I give awful legal advice.

Comment: @DrewDormann I am beginning to appreciate how complicated licensing issues are and why in the past companies I have worked with would rather rewrite functionality than need to rely on anything they hadn't themselves done.

Comment: Telerik are pretty responsive in [their forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight.aspx) and in most cases answer no later that 72 hours, so just go ahead and ask your question there. I'll appreciate if you post the answer back here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of RadControls, you need to recompile the assemblies using protection that only your app can load. Then you can redistribute the software as long as you give proper  copyright messages for telerik:

Taken from the [License Agreement for Silverlight](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/license-agreement/silverlight.aspx)

1.3 Redistribution Rights.

1.3.1 Subject to the terms of this Agreement, You are granted a limited license to redistribute the Software solely as part of bundled software solutions for internal company use, hosted applications, commercial solutions deployed at Your Authorized End-Users sites, or shrink-wrapped software offerings in which the Software is integrated (collectively “Integrated Products”). “Integrated Products”, as defined herein, are limited to those software solutions which: (i) are developed by Your Licensed Developers; (ii) add substantial functionality beyond the functionality provided by the incorporated components of the Software; and (iii) are not commercial alternatives for, or competitive in the marketplace with, the Software or any components of the Software.

To recompile the assemblies using protection, you can follow the steps listed on this page - [Protecting Telerik RadControls assembly](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/protecting-telerik-radcontrols-assembly.html)